PostgreSQL: permission denied to COPY to or from an external program, even after Grant pg_execute_server_program
Running Copy test(id, name) From Program 'zcat /tmp/test.csv.gz' CSV Header; fails with:
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied to COPY to or from an external program
Detail: Only roles with privileges of the "pg_execute_server_program" role may COPY to or from an external program.

even though it's been granted to the current user:
SELECT current_user;
-- report_mgr

 SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE
   pg_has_role(current_user, oid, 'member');

|rolname                  |
|-------------------------|
|pg_execute_server_program|
|report_mgr               |

Running on the official postgres:16 Docker image (PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit).
The query works fine with the postgres user, both in psql and SQLModel/SQLAlchemy, but haven't been able to get it to work for report_mgr. The file is readable, though that's irrelevant as the command is never executed. The user was created like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grant_on_schemas(
  role text,
  schemas text[],
  privilege text default 'select')
RETURNS SETOF text AS $$
DECLARE
  query text;
  schema text;
BEGIN
  query := format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO %s;', (SELECT current_database()), role);
  -- Add query to result table as a new row, then execute
  Return Next query;
  Execute query;
 
  FOREACH schema IN ARRAY schemas LOOP
      If privilege = 'select' Then
        -- Grant select
        query := format('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA %I TO %s;', schema, role);
        Return Next query;
        Execute query;
        query := format('GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA %I TO %s;', schema, role);
        Return Next query;
        Execute query;
        query := format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %I GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO %s;', schema, role);
        Return Next query;
        Execute query;
      Elsif privilege = 'all' Then
        -- Grant all
        query := format('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA %I TO %s;', schema, role);
        Return Next query;
        Execute query;
        query := format('GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA %I TO %s;', schema, role);
        Return Next query;
        Execute query;
        -- Apply them to new tables/views created by this admin account
        query := format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %I GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO %s;', schema, role);
        Return Next query;
        Execute query;
        -- Other permissions: functions, procedures, routines, sequences
      Else
        Return Next format('Error: privilege "%s" not found', privilege);
      End If;
  END LOOP;
  Return;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Create Role report_mgr login password 'qwert';
Select grant_on_schemas('report_mgr', array['public'], 'all');
Grant pg_execute_server_program To report_mgr;

Any ideas will be appreciated.

@LaurenzAlbe: "Running on the official postgres:16 Docker image (PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit)."

Thanks, I didn't see that. Well, whoever runs that COPY is not a member of pg_execute_server_program. Make sure that you connect to the correct cluster as the correct user.

works for me.  I'd guess you are not actually logged in as who you think you are at one point in this event.

Harrumph.  Blind paranoia (and copy-pastas) bit my rear again.  I actually created the user with Create Role report_mgr login noinherit password 'qwert';, so of course he was not inheriting the privilege.  Recreating without noinherit did the trick.
Thanks everyone!
